# Очистка таблиц базы

Tags: sql, база-данных

Как удалить все данные из всех таблиц базы?

Answer (score 1):

А никак. 
По одной таблице чистить, желательно ручками, так как данные могут быть связанными.

СУБД какая?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте схему базы данных.
Там можно обойти все таблицы и для каждой выполнить инструкцию удаления данных.